# Generating Apple Wallet Pass

Tags: ios, applepay, passbook, apple-wallet

I'm trying to generate Apple Wallet pass for one of my client but for some reasons related to Certificate signing I cannot generate a valid pass file. I've tried to use public key and private key for generating the Wallet pass but no success.

I might be missing the correct files here, can someone please guide me through the file generation process here?

There is no issue with my Web service to generate the .pkpass file by using an old certificate file (Issued by WWDR bak in 2020).

I'm using this [pass file validator](https://pkpassvalidator.azurewebsites.net/) to validate the file.

attached screenshot for[image: validation response]

Comment: Hi Joe. I'm the developer who created pkpassvalidator. Are you using the G4 WWDR certificate? Also, how did you generate the CSR For your passkit certificate? Did you look at the advice under https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/pkpassvalidator/wiki/PassKit-certificate-contains-an-incorrect-value?

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I did read these instructions following the Read more here link. But its still the same result.

Comment: And which key do i need to export private or public(.p12 ) from keychain access? and yes i'm using G4 WWDR certificate.

Comment: The p12 should contain both the public and private components. You can select both rows in Keychain Assistant and export them together.